# Проброс исключения из одного метода в другой

Tags: php, исключения

Хочу написать свой простенький класс обертку для работы с базой. Подключение будет происходить через **PDO** к базе **Oracle**. Будет входная точка, в которую будут поступать **HTT**P запросы, данный скрипт обработчик будет создавать объект моего класса **DB**, но в случае ошибки подключения к **Oracle** не просто убивать скрипт внутри класса, но обработать ошибку и вернуть какое то результат.

На сколько будет логичен следующий код? Я хочу пробросить исключение которое выкинуло *PDO*

```
<?php

class DB
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->checkConnection();
    }

    public function checkConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            $this->connect();
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            throw $e;
        } 
    }

    public function connect()
    {
        // Здесь будет подключение к Oracle DB через PDO
        throw new Exception("Faiied connection to database");
    }
}

try
{
    $db = new DB();
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: И зачем в итоге ловить исключение, а потом его снова выбрасывать?

Comment: Да уже заметил это спасибо.

Comment: Просто если я не выброшу еще одно исключение в методе checkConnection то, я уже не смогу обрабатывать ошибки подключени при создании объекта.

Comment: Какой в данном случае смысл прятать все в три уровня функций? Почему нельзя нужный код сразу разместить в конструкторе?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нужно просто пробросить исключение выше, то блок try-catch писать не нужно, все исключения всплывают автоматически до try-catch, либо завершают выполнение скрипта, если не были пойманы.

Однако, использовать try-catch в методе `checkConnection` имеет смысл, если ты хочешь ввести свои исключения.

https://3v4l.org/IYuPv

```
<?php

class MyDbException extends Exception {}

class DB 
{
    public function __construct() {
        $this->checkConnection();
    }

    public function checkConnection() {
        try {
            $this->connect();
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            throw new MyDbException('Error during connection check', 42, $e);
        }
    }

    public function connect() {
        // Здесь будет подключение к Oracle DB через PDO
        throw new PDOException("SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'user'@'example.com' (using password: YES)");
    }
}

function connectToDb() {
    try {
        $db = new DB;
        // ...
    }
    catch (MyDbException $e) {
        echo sprintf("[%s] %s:\n\n%s", $e->getCode(), $e->getMessage(), $e->getPrevious()->getMessage());
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage(), PHP_EOL;
    }
}

connectToDb();
```

```
[42] Error during connection check:

SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'user'@'example.com' (using password: YES)
```